# Doe desirability 3D plot doverall - R software

Tags: r, optimization, plot, 3d

I generated models thanks to a DOE approach on one pilot and now I want to optimize them by looking for a optimized point. To do this, I would like to generated a 3D plot of the overall desirability according to the optimization wished.  However, I know the theory but I do not success to generate the associated code in R. Can you help me?

Here a study case where at the end there is the kind of plot that I would like to obtain: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section5/pri5322.htm

My data example:

```
#environment
install.packages("desirability")
library(desirability)

#Models generated:
mod1<- function(x) 42.08187+x[1]*-14.4875+x[2]*-14.92375+x[3]*-15.68625+x[1]^2*0+x[2]^2*0+x[3]^2*0+x[2]*x[1]*0+x[1]*x[3]*0+x[2]*x[3]*-4.5725
mod2<- function(x) 9.97+x[1]*4.28+x[2]*0+x[3]*-0.88+x[1]^2*0+x[2]^2*0+x[3]^2*0.43+x[2]*x[1]*0+x[1]*x[3]*-0.32+x[2]*x[3]*0

#my wished optimization  
opt.mod1<-dMin(40,50)
opt.mod2<-dTarget(55, 57.5, 60)
```

I do not not understand how to proceed to generated the 3plot with desirability value (min:0 and max:1) in Z axis and with x1  and x2 in X and Y axis, respectively.

In theory, the  overall desirability is: D = (d1*d2*...dr)^(1/r)

where d1 and d2 are wished optimization.

How can I generate the 3D plot ? I have tried a lot of things (as, persp function with plotGird) but it failled everytime and made me crazy and  desperate.

I hope my problem is clear. I am sur that is not a big business.

Thanks a lot.

John